# is the presheaf category of a locally small category locally small?

Tags: ct.category-theory

e.g.  is $\widehat{\mathbf{SET}}$ locally small?

Comment: doesn't this depend on the precise definition of locally small and SET (e.g. with Grothendieck universes)? I think there are varying answers, depending which definitions you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in general. Todd gave a useful general answer and here is a concrete counter-example.

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category whose objects are sets and where the only morphisms are the identities. Consider the functors $F, G : \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ given by $F(X) = 1 = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $G(X) = 2 = \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$. Because $\mathbf{C}$ is discrete, every family of maps $(\eta_X : F(X) \to G(X))_{X \in \mathbf{C}}$ is natural. Therefore, natural transformations $F \to G$ are in bijective correspondence with classes:

- a natural transformation $\eta : F \to G$ corresponds to the class $\lbrace X \in \mathbf{Set} \mid \eta_X(0) = 1\rbrace$.
- a class $C$ corresponds to the natural transformation $\eta : F \to G$ given by

  > $\eta_X(0) = 1$ if $X \in C$ and $\eta_X(0) = 0$ if $X \not\in C$.

Thus the presheaf category $\widehat{\mathbf{C}}$ is not locally small (note that $\mathbf{C}^{op} = \mathbf{C}$).

I cannot think at the moment of concrete presheaves $F$ and $G$ on $\mathbf{Set}$ for which the natural transformations $F \to G$ form a proper class. Someone please help.

Comment: Andrej, did you take a look at the Freyd-Street paper? Because their construction is quite explicit and concrete: see their definition of a functor "T". 

Comment: I looked after you posted your answer (I was writing mine when yours arrived). I just wanted to give as easy a counter-example as possible.

Comment: I meant not with regard to your counter-example, but with regard to your plea at the end (but maybe you understood that's what I meant! :-) 



Answer (score 7):

There's a theorem due to Freyd and Street that says that if $C$ is locally small and the presheaf category $Set^{C^{op}}$ is locally small, then $C$ is equivalent to a small category. See [this paper](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1995/n9/v1n9.pdf).

Comment: @Todd Trimble: Is this simple argument wrong? Consider a non-empty hom-set $\widehat{C}(F,G)$, and let $\tau$ be in this hom-set.  If the hom-set is small, then by transitivity of the universe, $\tau$ is small too. But $\tau$ is just a function with domain $\operatorname{obj}(C)$ (so $\tau$ is a triple with $\operatorname{obj}(C)$ as its first
component).  But then from transitivity again we get
$\operatorname{obj}(C)\in U$, a contradiction. (So, in general,the
answer to the original question is ``no'')

Comment: Even if $C$ is large, the collection of transformations $F \to G$ between presheaves can be essentially small (in definable isomorphism with a set). Consider for example $F$ representable and apply Yoneda. 

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I hope it is OK that I ask another silly question:  Is my comment above correct, but just useless, because (for some reason that I still don't understand) "locally small" can refer to non-small hom-sets that are in bijection with small sets? [I'm assuming a single universe, as in Mac Lane.]

Comment: Yes, under the sorts of set-theoretic encodings you appear to have in mind, the argument looks to me impeccable but still "morally wrong"! (It would mean $\hom(F, G)$ is not small even if $G$ is terminal.) It's an excellent illustration of the kind of sophistry that's possible by encoding everything as sets and sets as membership trees. More satisfactory would be a foundations where this type of argument cannot even be formulated (cf. discussion of structuralist vs. materialist forms of set theory in the nLab). Suffice it to say that the problem is not insurmountable. :-)


Comment: Thank you very much!  Having such tips from an expert is extremely helpful.  I have a million more question to ask, but I guess these comments aren't the right place for such a mini course...

Comment: Obviously there's a lot to add, but you're right: these little comment boxes are not the best place. There are various possibilities for "alternative foundations" which avoids these strange glitches. One is ETCS (due to Lawvere), which you can begin reading about at the nLab or from <a href="http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/11/tr11abs.html">Lawvere himself</a>. (But for some people, ETCS is hard and technical, and not as intuitive as ZFC.) Another very intriguing possibility is Mike Shulman's SEAR (exclusively at the nLab, AFAIK). 


Comment: Thanks for the pointers!  The link doesn't seem to work, but I will look at nLab now that I know what to look for.  I suppose that at the moment (before finished reading Mac Lane) I'll stick to the foundations described in Section 1.6 of Mac Lane.  Although limited (as I now see..), these foundations seem to be sufficient in Mac Lane (as Mike Shulman told me in a comment...), and I should probably not "dive" into something else right now.  Thanks again for your help.